# pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "x" does not exist LINE 2: SET name=x

Tags: php, postgresql, facebook-graph-api

I have been working on something like a sign up form for a facebook app but instead of INSERT it UPDATE because before that I have already INSERT

```
$inserP = "INSERT INTO particular (id, name)
VALUES ($userid, 0)";
pg_query($conn, $inserP);
```

and I come across this error after submitting the form with the username tom:

```
pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "tom" does not exist LINE 2: SET name=tom
```

Here is my form

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" /> 
<input type="image" name="confirm" src="/images/confirm.png"/>
</form>
```

Here is my update.php

```
require('conn.php');
require('getfacebookapi.php');
$userid = idx($facebook->api('/me/'), 'id', string);
$username=$_POST['username'];
$pszz = "UPDATE particular
SET name=$username
WHERE id=$userid";
  if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/", $username)) {       
    pg_query($conn, $pszz);}
```

There is absolutely nothing wrong with my pg_pconnect.. Can someone tell me where I went wrong and how to fix this error? I'm new to both php and sql... Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never, never compose SQL statements by string concatenation or interpolation. Use bind parameters ([PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or at least [`pg_query_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around your strings values, otherwise it will think it's a column. 
SET name='tom'
WHERE id='someid'

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a text field; inserting into text fields requires single-quotes around the value: `'tom'`